Who owns the Upgrade Authority for the SPL Token Program?
See title.
We know that the Upgrade Authority is not closed on the Solana SPL Token Program, so who owns it, and is there clear ownership tree or planned changes to be made to the SPL Token Program?

The SPL Token program is not technically upgradeable. You'll see that it's owned by BPF Loader 2 and not BPF Upgradeable Loader: https://explorer.solana.com/address/TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
In the past, it has been upgraded through consensus-breaking changes to replace the program account. But it hasn't been upgraded that way in a couple of years.
